# Survey data and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-variable, survey

I am wondering if a certain thing is possible. I think it might not, but some of my colleagues try to persuade me that it it indeed possible. So here is the problem:

I have some survey data, where respondents respond to a 3 questions on a 0-5 scale, 5 being the highest value. Now I want to sum up the responses of all respondents to obtain a grand total score for each question. Let's say that I have values 100, 250, 500 (with the sum being 850). Now I transform thse values to percentage amounts of total score, i.e., 100/850 ~ 12% etc. Is it now possible to statistically test that the percentage score created from the answers to question one (grand total 100) lies in a percentage interval of (10%, 15%), which is specified up-front? From what I gather this is not a typical statistical test with the t-stat.

The main doubt is connected to the fact that individual responses are random variables. But what about the sum of the random variables (which creates the score, and later the percentage value)?

I would be grateful for any help with this problem!

Comment: What meaning is there in the sum of the ordinal/ranking scores?

Comment: I get the information how much importance was assigned to one of the selected questions.